Windows server 2019, Domain Controller, Server Core, Setup task in Task Scheduler returning error 2147942450
Hoping for some help with this issue I've been fighting the past couple days. I have attempted to create a task on my secondary domain controller to send an email when it is rebooted or whenever it powers on.
I'm copying the exact same setup as my other domain controller in every way possible. same name, location user account and settings.
The only thing I am unable to keep the same is the Configure For box which has the only option at "Windows server 2003, windows XP or windows 2000" whereas on my other domain controller windows server 2016 server core it says windows 10. and has other options for "windows 7, server2008 r2" and "windows vista, windows server 2008" When trying to just create it with the option set to 2003 XP or 2000 I get the error code "2147942450" an error code which has seemingly no presence on the internet? What am I missing here?
